# char array in switch statement with strange error message

Tags: c

I have a question.
I have declared a char as a array and depending on an other parameter this array has to look different.

```
char map[10][10];
switch(stage){
case 1:
//Map NR1
map [10][10]={
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ','#',' ','&',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#','S','T','A','G','E','1',' ',' ','#'},      
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'} };
    break;
case 2:
//Map NR2
map [10][10]={
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ','&',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#','S','T','A','G','E','2',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'}, };
    break;
    }
```

Now is my question: Why do I get this?:

```
main.c: In function 'map_initialisation':
main.c:32:15: error: expected expression before '{' token
  map [10][10]={
               ^
main.c:46:15: error: expected expression before '{' token
  map [10][10]={
               ^
```

What is wrong in this code excerpt

Comment: Please read some basic C tutorials/books.

Comment: At your 2nd map declaration at the end you dont need to write a ,!

Answer (score 3):

You can only use special initialization syntax when you first declare map, not later on. Try something like this:

```
char map1[10][10]={
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ','#',' ','&',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#','S','T','A','G','E','1',' ',' ','#'},      
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'} };

char map2[10][10]={
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ','&',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#','S','T','A','G','E','2',' ',' ','#'},
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'}, };

char (*current_level)[10];

switch(stage)
{
    case 1:
        current_level = map1;
        break;

    case 2:
        current_level = map2;
        break;
}
```

Edit: Fixed a slight typing issue

Comment: hey that, with map1, map2, map(n+1) is what I wanted to avoid, because of that I have to make a switch statement in about 6 other functions vor each map

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are getting at, but you might take a look at Alok's answer below. His solution allows you to put all of your maps into an array, so you can access them with `maps[n]` instead of with a `switch` block.

Comment: oh sorry, now I realized it.

I can delcare the maps map1 ... map n, map(n+1)
after that I am changing their name depending on the parameter

Answer (score 2):

As others said, you can't assign to arrays.

I recommend you change your data structure a little bit:

```
char maps[][10][10] = {
    {
        "##########",
        "#        #",
        "#     #  #",
        "#     #  #",
        "# # & #  #",
        "# #   #  #",
        "# #####  #",
        "#        #",
        "#STAGE1  #",
        "##########"
    },
    {
        "##########",
        "#        #",
        "#     #  #",
        "#     #  #",
        "# &   #  #",
        "# #   #  #",
        "# #####  #",
        "#        #",
        "#STAGE2  #",
        "##########"
    }
};
size_t nmaps = sizeof maps / sizeof maps[0];
```

Then, you can do:

```
char (*map)[10];
if (stage > 0 and stage <= nmaps) {
    map = maps[stage - 1];
} else {
    /* handle error */
}
```

If you want the individual values to be strings (null-terminated), you need at least 11 characters.  So, then you will have to declare `maps` as `char maps[][10][11] = ...`, and change `map` declaration to `char (*map)[11];`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to declare the map only once even though it is very bad practice. I repeat this won't be nice, but will work. Goto haters stay away:

```
    int flag;
    switch(stage){
    case 1:
    //Map NR1
       goto first;
    case 2:
    //Map NR2
       goto second;
    }

first:
 char map [10][10]={
        {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ','#',' ','&',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#','S','T','A','G','E','1',' ',' ','#'},      
        {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'} };
  flag = 0;

if(flag != 0)
  goto third;
  second:
        char map [10][10]={
        {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ','&',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#','S','T','A','G','E','2',' ',' ','#'},
        {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'} };

   third: return 0;
```

Comment: In C, a declaration is not a statement (the rules are different in C++) and only statements can be labelled.

Comment: i didnt even knew about the goto function.

good to know that it can been made like this

Comment: @Spark Monkay  Apart from incorrect using the label this example of code is simply invalid because any declaration in if statement has scope only of this if statement. That is it will not be visible in any other part of the code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I beg to differ.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code that there is no assignment operator for arrays particulary that accepts an initializer list. But there is assignment operator for structures.

If your compiler supports C99 then you can use the following approach by means of compound literals and wrapping the array in a structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct MAP
{
    char map[10][10];
};

int main()
{
    struct MAP map; 
    int stage = 1;

    switch ( stage )
    {
        case 1:
            map =
            ( struct MAP ){
                {
                    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#',' ','&',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#','S','T','A','G','E','1',' ',' ','#'},      
                    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'}
                }
            };
            break;

        case 2:
            map = 
            ( struct MAP ){
                {
                    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','&',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#','S','T','A','G','E','2',' ',' ','#'},
                    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'}, 
                }
            };
            break;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) printf( "%c", map.map[i][j] );
        puts( "" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
##########
#        #
#     #  #
#     #  #
# # & #  #
# #   #  #
# #####  #
#        #
#STAGE1  #
##########
```

You could make the code more readable by introducing macros

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct MAP
{
    char map[10][10];
};

#define STAGE1 \
{\
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},\
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#',' ','#',' ','&',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#','S','T','A','G','E','1',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'}\
}

#define STAGE2 \
{\
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},\
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#',' ','&',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#',' ','#',' ',' ',' ','#',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#',' ','#','#','#','#','#',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#','S','T','A','G','E','2',' ',' ','#'},\
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},\
}

int main()
{
    struct MAP map; 
    int stage = 1;

    switch ( stage )
    {
        case 1:
            map = ( struct MAP ){ STAGE1 };
            break;

        case 2:
            map = ( struct MAP ){ STAGE2 };
            break;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) printf( "%c", map.map[i][j] );
        puts( "" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```